is there any rule Sonos groupId change?
i am trying to develop an app to control sonos product.i use Control API to do that. What puzzles me is that the groupId is transient and changeable, but there is many api need groupId .Is there any rule in groupId change ?
I tried to see how it changed, but I had no clue.I did not delete the group, nor did I create the group. But it changed.
